# Convert IDs from List<T> to string[]

Tags: c#

I have a `List<MyClass>`

and `MyClass` is defined as

```
class MyClass
{
 public string ID{get; set;};
 public string Name{get; set;};
}
```

Now i want to collect all the IDs alone from the List of MyClass objects i have and convert it into string [].

How to accomplish this?

Am not familiar with LINQ. That is why i was asking.

I dont know what to say but the downvotes made me really take a look at LINQ and projections so thanks for sharing that info.

Comment: Did you try anything? Looping using `foreach()`, projecting using Linq?

Comment: Did foreach of course. but was looking for single line/ 2 line way of achieving this.

Comment: Then next time please explain what you have tried and what you are looking for.

Comment: @CodeCaster What he is looking for is quite obvious. But I agree on the rest.

Comment: @Adam _"What he is looking for is quite obvious"_ - no it isn't. Is he looking for a C# For Dummies book that explains loops and Linq, or is there any specific error in his current approach he wishes to address? The only current flaw I get from the question and comments is that the current code is too long. Questions with so little detail aren't real questions, or too localized as they'll be unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: @CodeCaster "Convert IDs from List<T> to string[]" followed by some code showing a list of `MyClass` and a definition featuring an `ID` property. I'm sorry, but I find that quite obvious (barring any further information that contradicts the way I interpret it). His end goal was obvious, what was not obvious was whether there was a specific way to get there. I think this has benefit to future visitors, they can learn about projections in linq thanks to this. That said, it's very likely a duplicate of another flavour of the same somewhere. The question was thread bare, but I've seen worse.

Comment: @Adam I can read. I asked what OP was looking for because _"How can I convert collection type X to type Y"_ can be answered in various ways, and the selection of the best way depends on what OP has currently done and what wasn't satisfactory about that. It was a question meant to pull more information out of OP, in order to be able to perhaps make this a useful question for others. Now it's just too localized.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is now arguing over semantics. Suffice to say, I've seen much worse questions than this. The only gripe I can find with this is that it has multiple equally valid solutions, but then lots of questions on SO do. I'm not going to refuse to answer it if I can see an answer to a valid interpretation that covers what was provided - I just stand to be corrected should the OP provide more details. I disagree that it is too localized as it demonstrates projection in Linq. It is, however, just one more example of many on SO, very likely duplicated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use projection in LINQ:

```
var ids = myClassList.Select(myClass => myClass.ID).ToArray();
```

Under `using System.Linq;`

The [`Select` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) allows you to "project" a type into something else (including anonymous types). With the new type inference mechanisms in the compiler you don't even need to specify the generic arguments for `Select`.

The `Select` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` in this case.

`ToArray` does as it says on the tin, converts the `IEnumerable<T>` into a `T[]`.

Projection is just fancy terminology for a [subset of Linq methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx), the work is done by your own code (in the above case this is the lambda expression: `myClass => myClass.ID`). The `Select` method takes a `Func<TSource, TResult>`, and whatever your code returns will be what `TResult` becomes, in this case we return a `string` property of `MyClass` so you get a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple LINQ query using the `select` extension method:

```
List<MyClass> collection = new List<MyClass>() {new MyClass(), new MyClass()};
string[] result = collection.Select(b => b.ID).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
var idArray = list.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
```